# Create message in console when specific dataframe cells are empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe in the following structure (here only the first 4 rows)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Bread':[3,"Nan","Nan", 0],
       'Butter': ["Nan", "Nan", "Nan", 1],
       'Jam': ["Nan", "Nan", "Nan", 0.7]})

 Bread Butter  Jam
0     3    Nan  Nan
1   Nan    Nan  Nan
2   Nan    Nan  Nan
3     0      1  0.7

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Bread':[3,"Nan","Nan", 0],
       'Butter': ["Nan", "Nan", "Nan", 1],
       'Jam': ["Nan", 2, "Nan", 0.7]})

  Bread Butter  Jam
0     3    Nan  Nan
1   Nan    Nan    2
2   Nan    Nan  Nan
3     0      1  0.7
```

I would like to create a message in the Python console  with this text (Butter and Jam missing) in case the 3 rows have Nan values for both Butter and Jam. In case there is another value for either Butter or Jam in the first three rows the message does not appear.

In the example above the message would come with df1 but not with df2

Comment: Do `NaN`'s need to be consecutive? In case of 6 couples of `NaN`s but 2 consecutive triplets, does the message need to be printed twice?

Comment: Yes, they need to be consecutive. Here I asked specifically the first 3 rows in the dataframe, but a more versatile feature would be anytime there are three rows behind each other where Butter and Jam are Nan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First test `Nan`s string with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) or `NaN`s like missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) in both columns for boolean mask `m` with :

```
m = df1[['Butter','Jam']].eq('Nan').all(axis=1)
#m = df1[['Butter','Jam']].isna().all(axis=1)
```

Or:

```
m = df1['Butter'].eq('Nan') & df1['Jam'].eq('Nan')
#m = df1['Butter'].isna() & df1['Jam'].isna()

print (m)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Then check 3 consecutive `True` values and count them to new mask called `mask`:

```
mask = m.groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m]).transform('size').eq(3)
```

Last create new column:

```
df1['3 consecutive vals'] = np.where(mask, 'Butter and Jam missing', '')
```

---

```
print (df1)
  Butter  Jam      3 consecutive vals
0    NaN  NaN  Butter and Jam missing
1    NaN  NaN  Butter and Jam missing
2    NaN  NaN  Butter and Jam missing
3      1  0.7
```

If need test only if at least one 3 consecutive values use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for counter:

```
mask1 = (m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m]).value_counts().eq(3)
print (mask1)
1    True
dtype: bool

if mask1.any():
    print ('Butter and Jam missing in 3 consecutive rows')
else:
    print ('Butter and Jam are NOT missing in 3 consecutive rows')
```

Test for second DataFrame:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Bread':[3,"Nan","Nan", 0],
       'Butter': ["Nan", "Nan", "Nan", 1],
       'Jam': ["Nan", 2, "Nan", 0.7]})


m = df2[['Butter','Jam']].eq('Nan').all(axis=1)
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

mask = m.groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m]).transform('size').eq(3)
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

df2['3 consecutive vals'] = np.where(mask, 'Butter and Jam missing', '')
print (df2)
  Bread Butter  Jam 3 consecutive vals
0     3    Nan  Nan                   
1   Nan    Nan    2                   
2   Nan    Nan  Nan                   
3     0      1  0.7
```

---

```
mask1 = (m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m]).value_counts().eq(3)
print (mask1)
3    False
1    False
dtype: bool

if mask1.any():
    print ('Butter and Jam missing in 3 consecutive rows')
else:
    print ('Butter and Jam are NOT missing in 3 consecutive rows')
```

Comment: Great work, thank you. A last question here, if I do not want to specify the columns by name (Butter, Jam) but use the last two columns in the dataframe, how would you change m = df1[['Butter','Jam']].eq('Nan').all(axis=1)

Comment: @MHanu - Then the best is use `m = df1.iloc[:, -2:].eq('Nan').all(axis=1)`

Comment: @MHanu - If check `print (df1.iloc[:, -2:])` it return last 2 columns

Comment: The code worked with the small sample, but when I tried it on my large dataframe it gave me this error: ValueError: Length of passed values is 13025, index implies 0

Comment: @MHanu - sorry, I think reason should be changed `mask1 = (m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m]).value_counts().eq(3)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197710/discussion-between-jezrael-and-mhanu).